# python. экспортировать из web-интерфейса определенные данные в шаблон excel

Tags: html, python, excel

Всем привет! Ребята, подскажите мне, пожалуйста: у меня есть таблица в web-интерфейсе. Мне нужно по кнопке производить выгрузку данных из определенных ячеек из этой таблицы в определенный шаблон  excel. Как мне это сделать?? (Кнопка у меня уже есть, какую функцию применить ?)
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

есть модуль xlsxwriter

Пример работы с ним:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook('export.xlsx', {'strings_to_urls': False})
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Facebook')
head_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'reaction_count', head_format)
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'comment_count', head_format)
worksheet.write(0, 2, 'comment_plugin_count', head_format)
worksheet.write(0, 3, 'share_count', head_format)
worksheet.write(0, 4, 'engagement_summ', head_format)
worksheet.write(0, 5, 'Real site URL', head_format)
for i, row in enumerate(Data):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(i+1, j, value)
workbook.close()
```

Документация - http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: большое спасибо, Алексей! буду пробовать!